# About measures which respect half-spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was wondering if there are measures known on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which somehow "nicely" see the half-spaces. I am not sure how to exactly quantify "nicely" and hence feel free to make your own interpretation.

To give an example of a scenario I would be interested in : given any pair of vectors of $(\vec{u}, \vec{x})$ each in $\mathbb{R}^n$ it uniquely defines a half-space $H^+(\vec{u},\vec{x})$ as the one whose boundary is orthogonal to $\vec{u}$ and contains $\vec{x}$ on the boundary and is in the direction of $\vec{u}$. So what I am asking is if there are measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in which given an $H^+(\vec{u},\vec{x})$ it is somehow "easy" to compute, $\mu (H^+(\vec{u},\vec{x}) )$.

Maybe there is a family of measures parametrized by $\vec{u}$ so that given an $\vec{u}$ for all $\vec{x}$, $\mu (H^+(\vec{u},\vec{x}) )$ is easy to compute.

Comment: Lebesgue measure is easy to compute, $\mu(H^+(\vec u,\vec x)) = \infty$.

Comment: Ah! I mean something which is finite! I want some kind of an $\vec{u}$ and/or $\vec{x}$ dependence, however mild!

Comment: That's rather broad. I can simply choose a homeomorphism $f : X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ from some other finite measure space $(X,\nu_X)$ (such as $X =$ the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\nu_X=$ the restriction of Lebesgue measure), and then push forward the measure $\nu_X$ under $f$, meaning $\mu(H^+(\vec u,\vec x)) = \nu_X(f^{-1}(H^+(\vec u,\vec x)))$.

Comment: Is there any nice and neat example of being able to do this where the numbers are analytically calculable?

Comment: The example in my previous comment is analytically calculable. Simply write down an analytic formula for a homeomorphism whose domain is the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and whose range is $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You mean an explicit homeomorphism which maps the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $H^+(\vec{u},\vec{x})$? But won't this approach produce the same value of $\mu ( H^+(\vec{u}, \vec{x} ) )$ for all $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{x}$?